# In man's stead: Downturn in usage of 'man' and its replacement

Tags: frequency-analysis

[image: Google Ngram showing usage of 'man' declining]

For the past century the usage of *man* has declined; it's decline quickened around 1970. These downturns make sense and correspond to a movement to use more gender neutral language.

What is replacing *man*? *People*, *human*<sup>1</sup> and *humans* are all more common today than a century ago but their increase does not compensate for *man*'s decline. Are writers simply making less species-wide generalizations?

<sup>1</sup> I forgot to include *humans* in the screen capture but the line barely leaves the x-axis.

*Update:*

@Josh commented that the situation looks quite different in recent years. This poses a separate question: why the uptick? I have not looked into whether *man* is being used differently in this increased usage.

[image: Google Ngram showing increased use of other terms]

Comment: Extending to more recent years, “man” appears to be picking up: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man%2Chuman%2C+people&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's still unsettled.

Comment: @HotLicks What is unsettled? People just aren't making claims about humanity until they've settled how to replace 'man'?

Comment: @Unrelated - There is still no general agreement as to suitable gender-neutral terms.

Comment: @HotLicks Maybe my question is unclear. I am not looking for the 'right answer' of what I *should* replace 'man' with but what people actually do replace man with

Comment: @Unrelated - It's unsettled.  People use all sorts of terms, depending on the context and their political leanings.

Comment: (I might use "humanity", depending on the context -- which you fail to provide.)

Comment: @HotLicks lol 'fail'; we could just say "didn't"

Comment: No, it's "failed".  A reasonable amount of context is REQUIRED for questions such as this.

Comment: @HotLicks  Humanity is hardly worth mentioning https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man%2Chuman%2Cmankind%2Cpeople%2Chumans%2Chumanity&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chuman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmankind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeople%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumans%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chumanity%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yeah, less and less, I'm afraid.

Comment: It would be hard or impossible to measure, but it's possible the increased usage is for something that is not covered by "human" or "people."

Comment: I can't prove this and the way I hear it, many people would much rather distort both vocabulary and grammar than think about what anything like what *man* means… which leads me to think they shouldn't be indulged.

I'd rather not blather on unless someone asks…

Answer (score 1):

The word "man" (singular) has never been primarily a synonym for "mankind" or "humanity at large". It has always been used primarily to mean either a singular person in general (before gender-inclusive language) or a male person in particular. Also, in my experience, gender-inclusive practices in literature do the following:

- avoid using "man" as a synonym for "person"
- when using examples of people, use women as well as men
- stop ignoring women's perspectives and contributions

Based on this, I don't think the words you used for your comparison are representative of the expected trend. Your graph seems to focus on "man" as a synonym for "people" (plural) instead on the most common (singular) use of the word, and fails to account for all changes created by gender-inclusive practices.

Here is the comparison I would recommend starting with:
[image]

This gives us the following approximate trends from 1970 to 2000 (I admit I just eyeballed it):

"man": -0.025

"human": +0.005

"person": +0.005

"woman": +0.01

Now here is the graph for the plural words:

[image]

And the approximate change 1970 - 2000:

"men": -0.015

"people": +0.007

"women": +0.022

"humans": +0.004

**The overall change is:**

**"man" or "men": -0.040%**

**all others:  +0.053%**

**This increase more than accounts for the decrease in the male nouns.**

As for the recent uptick, it's hard to say for sure, but I think it does have something to do with a reaction against gender-inclusive writing. How else can we explain the sharp increase in "men" together with a sharp decrease in "women", right after "women" had been more frequent than "men"?

[image]

Comment: "• (also Man) [ in sing. ] human beings in general; the human race: *places untouched by the ravages of man* (Oxford)

Comment: @Unrelated Yes, I'm well aware, but was that the first definition listed in the dictionary? if not, then my point stands--it's not the primary, most common definition of the word. It hasn't been since at least the 1500s. Since ngrams can't differentiate which meaning of the word is being used, your results for "man" are picking up mostly "male person" or "a person" instead of "mankind". So you have to graph all possible replacements for "man" and "men". There is no way to get ngams to show the partial picture for just one meaning, so you have to grab the whole picture and infer from there.

Comment: Your username is too apt. Definitely later than 1500. You're basically saying man has never been used collectively in Modern English. I presented ngrams as my demonstration of question. It doesn't need to also provide the answer